# How to pick oracle current_timestamp when saving grails domain object

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails version 2.4.0, java version 1.7 and oracle 12c.

I want to persist the records of `apiEventLogList` in the database table. Instead of setting `createdTs` field in java, I want to pick the oracle `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value in it when the GORM save the records in the DB.

```
class ApiEventLog {
    private Date startTs;
    private Date finishTs;
    private Date createdTs; 
}
```

```
apiEventLogList.each { it ->
    it.setStartTs(ApiEventLog.prevFinishTime)
    it.setFinishTs(currentDate)
    it.setCreatedTs(new Date())
    it.save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pick the oracle CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value in it when the GORM
>   save the records in the DB

If you have a `Date dateCreated` property in your domain class, GORM will initialize that field for you when you save the instance.

For more info see the **Auto Timestamping** section at https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.1/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping.

Comment: Note that is isn't exactly the same as referencing Oracles `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  Using our auto time stamping causes the `dateCreated` property effectively to be initialized with `new Date()` when the thing is saved, but that is happening in the app, not in the database.  If the the clock on the machine where the Grails app is running is not the same as the clock on the machine where the Oracle instance is running and you care about that difference, the auto time stamping feature isn't going to get you what you want.

Comment: Yes Jeff, this will not give the oracle date, in my case I am looking for oracle server date.

Comment: Then the answer is GORM doesn't support it.  You will have to send a request to Oracle to get the date there, then use that to initialize the property in your domain class and you will just have to deal with the difference in time caused by the network traffic, which probably isn't significant.  GORM won't be involved in any of that.